# Getting a write access violation

Tags: c

when the code is debugged one of my functions throws a write access exception and I'm not really sure why. the problem is being thrown from my computeFunction function whose goal is to set multiple values. it is called inside of a loop and has a bunch of int values passed in as well as the address for 4 doubles including homeOffense (which is the one throwing the exception).

I've looked at code that does what I'm trying to do and i cant really see a difference in what I've been doing.

```
void main() {

    int homeAttackStrength, homeDefensiveStrength, homeGoalieRating, homeFieldAdvg, homeExp, visitAttackStrength,
        visitDefensiveStrength, visitGoalieRating, visitRoad, visitExp, weather, hScore, vScore, gameCount, x;
    double homeOffense, visitO, crowd, experience,homeWinCount,drawCount,homeWin,draw;
    char home[20], visit[20];
    FILE *fpi1, *fpo1;

    fpi1 = fopen("soccer1.txt","r");

    homeWinCount = 0;
    drawCount = 0;
    gameCount = 0;
    x = 0;


    while (getInput(fpi1, home, &homeAttackStrength, &homeDefensiveStrength, &homeGoalieRating, &homeFieldAdvg, &homeExp,
        visit, &visitAttackStrength, &visitDefensiveStrength, &visitGoalieRating, &visitRoad, &visitExp, &weather) != EOF) {


        computeFunctions(homeAttackStrength, homeDefensiveStrength, homeGoalieRating, homeFieldAdvg, homeExp, visitAttackStrength,
            visitDefensiveStrength, visitDefensiveStrength, visitGoalieRating, visitRoad, visitExp, &homeOffense, &visitO, &crowd, &experience);
...

void computeFunctions(int homeAttackStrength, int homeDefensiveStrength, int homeGoalieRating, int homeFieldAdvg, int homeExp,
    int visitAttackStrength, int visitDefensiveStrength, int visitGoalieRating, int visitRoad, int visitExp, double *homeOffense, 
    double *visitO, double *crowd, double *experience) {

    *homeOffense= (HOME_SCORING_ADVANTAGE * homeAttackStrength + HOME_SCORING_ADJUSTMENT) / (((long double)visitDefensiveStrength + (long double)visitGoalieRating) * AWAY_IMPACT);
    *visitO= ((long double)visitAttackStrength + (long double)visitExp) * AWAY_IMPACT - ((long double)homeDefensiveStrength + (long double)homeGoalieRating + homeExp * EXPERIENCE_ADJUSTMENT);
    *crowd= HOME_FIELD_IMPACT * homeFieldAdvg / visitRoad;
    *experience= ((long double)homeExp - (long double)visitExp) * EXPERIENCE_ADJUSTMENT;
}
```

the error messgae is:

> Exception thrown: write access violation.

`homeOffense` was `0x2`.

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the access violation is happening because you are trying to write a long double into a double pointer. The size of a long double is definitely more than a double, therefore, writing a long double into a double would end up in writing into some location which is beyond the permissible address. This is similar to doing *char_ptr = long_val which can crash. 
Could you please try casting the calculation results before writing into the homeOffense, visit0, and experience pointers? Maybe it will solve the crash issue.